# Generating an ascii table from data in a text file

Tags: python, list, random, ascii

I am creating a program that can generate characters for D&D 5e. To do this I need to create an inventory for the characters. To create this inventory, I need to take a selection of unique items and store them in a list. From this I have a `.txt` file that I am reading from and trying to select the items from. A snippet of this below:

```yaml
Abacus,2 gp,2 lb,2
Acid (vial),25 gp,1 lb,15
Alchemist's fire (flask),50 gp,1 lb,1
...
```

The area that I am having issues with is to create an ascii table with this data. Every solution, that I have thought of has been verbose and definitely not near to the optimal solution. I have attached the code I am using below: (some code has been omitted for conciseness)

````
```python
import random
from random import choice

item_cat = ["Item","Cost","Weight","Amount"]

def file_to_list(filename): 
   thefile = open(filename,"r")
   rows = [line for line in thefile]
   thefile.close()
    for i,r in enumerate(rows):
        rows[i] = r.replace("\n","")
    return rows

i = file_to_list("Items.txt")

def items():

def presentation():
    lines()
    print("Equipment:")
    
presentation()
```
````

Comment: `rows = [line.rstrip() for line in thefile]`, `x = [random.randint(9,17) for _ in range(6)]`

Comment: When you say table, can you use for example pandas DataFrames? And also, the different lines inside the txt files are separate with a "." or with a "\n"?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre The .txt file is separated with "\n". What I mean by table is ascii table. I would like to generate an ascii table for the collected items.